# How to store a form submission into a textfile

Tags: php, html, radio-button, text-files

I have a text file with multiple lines. I have to display the contents of each line as a separate radio button then store the user's selection in another text file. I did the 'reading the file and displaying as radio buttons' part using PHP.

```
<?php
         $file = fopen("XYZ.txt", "r");
         //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
         echo "ABC" . "<br>";
         while(!feof($file))
         {
              $f = fgets($file);
              if (strpos ($f, ".abc") !== false)
              {
                 echo "<input type='radio' name='abc'/>";
                 echo "<a href = \"ftp://blah/".$f."\">" .$f. "</a><br>";
              }
         }
         fclose($file); 
?>
```

I used `<a>` because I had to link each of the radio buttons to a site. I don't know how to store the selection in a text file. :(

Comment: You need an HTML form, then by submitting the form the values are sent to the server. You don't use a link for this type of thing.

Comment: The link is not for submitting the radio button selection. It's something like this; the text file that I had to read had a list of files in it. I had to select all the .abc files and display them as radio button options. Before the user selects one of the options, he can click on the link to see the contents of that file. So essentially, it's something like
    -O <link1>
    -O <link2>
    -O <link3>
    Instead of: 
    -O <text1> 
    -O <text2>
    -O <text3>

Comment: You should have the contents in the page at load-time, hidden, then make them visible on click. jQuery can help you build this using JavaScript.

Comment: How is that going to help me store the selection in a text file?

Comment: Does this help you? http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=757223 (You'll need `$_REQUEST['abc']` instead of `$_POST['data']`, forget about the saving part)

Comment: The question you are asking has nothing to do with the tile of the question. Something as `How to store a form submission into a textfile` would be more apropriate.

Comment: That was not really what I was looking for. But I think I might have figured it out. I will just have to get the new text (all the names with .abc extension) from the file that I read at the beginning, and store it in another file. Then use HTML instead of PHP to write it as a radio group. That way I can access what the user has selected.
And my title was supposed to be "Radio button selection to textfile" I don't know how I wrote the opposite. But your suggestion definitely sounds more appropriate. Thanks!